# Explicit content music not appearing on my iPhone

Tags: ios, music, apple-music, music.app

I have added to my iPhone a new album which includes explicit music. When I check on iTunes I can see the music is on my iPhone, but when I search for these songs on my iPhone I can't find them.

**What do I have to do to make this album visible?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could check is whether Resrictions are enabled on your iPhone.

To do this:

1. On your iPhone tap on **Settings**
2. Swipe up and tap on **General**
3. Look for the Restrictions option and check to the right of it to see if they are *Off* or *On*.
4. If Restrictions are Off, then it won't be a restrictions issue and you can skip the rest of these steps.
5. If Restrictions are On, and you know the restrictions passcode, then tap on Restrictions and enter the passcode.
6. Once the Restrictions list appears, swipe up until you see the Allowed Content list
7. The second item on the list includes your Music restrictions. Tap on this and check to see if Explicit is enabled or disabled. If it's toggled to Off then you can't play back explicit music. If it's toggled on (i.e. it's green) then you can.

**NOTE:** If you get to Step 5, the restrictions passcode is most likely **not** the same as your iPhone's normal passcode. So if you try entering that and it doesn't work, do not keep trying to enter it. Instead you will need to speak to the person (e.g. a parent) who would have enabled restrictions to begin with.